# Blazor Web App Fluent UI Dialog component

Tags: c#, blazor, .net-8.0, fluent-ui

Hello im getting stuck on a demo to display dialog component, im getting the following errors:

- Attribute 'Parameter' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'property, indexer' declarations.
- Attribute 'CascadingParameter' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'property, indexer' declarations.

im trying to open a dialog with person object passed from a datagrid:
my datagrid page:

```
@page "/people"
@rendermode InteractiveServer

<h3>People</h3>

<FluentDataGrid Items="@FilteredPeople" ResizableColumns=true>
    <PropertyColumn Property="@(p => p.PersonId)" Sortable="true" />
    <PropertyColumn Property="@(p => p.Name)" Sortable="true">
        <ColumnOptions>
            <div class="search-box">
                <FluentSearch type="search" Autofocus=true @bind-Value=nameFilter @oninput="HandleNameFilter" @bind-Value:after="HandleClear" Placeholder="name..." />
            </div>
        </ColumnOptions>
    </PropertyColumn>
    <PropertyColumn Property="@(p => p.BirthDate)" Format="yyyy-MM-dd" Sortable="true" />
    <TemplateColumn Title="Actions" Align="@Align.End">
        <FluentButton BackgroundColor="var(--highlight-bg)" Color="var(--info)" IconEnd="@(new Icons.Regular.Size16.Edit())" OnClick="@(() => EditPerson(context))"/>
        <FluentButton Color="#ff0000" IconEnd="@(new Icons.Regular.Size16.Delete())" @onclick="@(() => DeletePerson(context))" />
    </TemplateColumn>
</FluentDataGrid>
```

code behind

```
using FleuntBlazorWebApp.UI.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components;

namespace FleuntBlazorWebApp.UI.Pages
{
    public partial class People
    {
        public record Person(int PersonId, string Name, DateOnly BirthDate);
        string nameFilter = string.Empty;

        static IQueryable<Person> people = new[]
        {
            new Person(10895, "Jean Martin", new DateOnly(1985, 3, 16)),
            new Person(10944, "António Langa", new DateOnly(1991, 12, 1)),
            new Person(11203, "Julie Smith", new DateOnly(1958, 10, 10)),
            new Person(11205, "Nur Sari", new DateOnly(1922, 4, 27)),
            new Person(11898, "Jose Hernandez", new DateOnly(2011, 5, 3)),
            new Person(12130, "Kenji Sato", new DateOnly(2004, 1, 9)),
        }.AsQueryable();

        IQueryable<Person>? FilteredPeople => people?.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(nameFilter, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

        private void HandleClear()
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nameFilter))
            {
                nameFilter = string.Empty;
            }
        }

        private void HandleNameFilter(ChangeEventArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Value is string value)
            {
                nameFilter = value;
            }
        }

        void DeletePerson(Person person)
        {
            Person personToRemove = people.FirstOrDefault(p => p == person);

            if (personToRemove != null)
            {
                people = people.Where(p => p != person).AsQueryable();
            }

            ToastService.ShowSuccess("Person deleted");
        }


        async Task EditPerson(Person person)
        {
            var dialog = await DialogService.ShowDialogAsync<PersonDialog>(person, new DialogParameters()
            {
                Height = "240px",
                Title = $"Updating the {person.Name} sheet",
                PreventDismissOnOverlayClick = true,
                PreventScroll = true,
            });

            var result = await dialog.Result;
            if (!result.Cancelled && result.Data != null)
            {
                person = (Person)result.Data;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

dialog component:

```
@implements IDialogContentComponent

<FluentDialogBody>
    <FluentTextField @bind-Value="@Content.Name">Name:</FluentTextField>
    <FluentNumberField @bind-Value="@Content.BirthDate">Age:</FluentNumberField>
    Test
</FluentDialogBody>

@code{
    [Parameter]
    public FleuntBlazorWebApp.UI.Pages.People.Person Content;

    [CascadingParameter]
    public FluentDialog Dialog;

    private async Task SaveAsync()
    {
        await Dialog.CloseAsync(Content);
    }

    private async Task CancelAsync()
    {
        await Dialog.CancelAsync();
    }
}
```

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Ok i changed this: `public record Person(int PersonId, string Name, DateOnly BirthDate);`

to this:

```
public record Person
{
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateOnly BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

and the collection to this:

```
static IQueryable<Person> people = new[]
{
            new Person(){PersonId = 10895, Name = "Jean Martin", BirthDate = new DateOnly(1985, 3, 16)},
            new Person(){PersonId = 10944, Name = "António Langa", BirthDate = new DateOnly(1991, 12, 1)},
            new Person(){PersonId = 11203, Name = "Julie Smith", BirthDate = new DateOnly(1958, 10, 10)},
            new Person(){PersonId = 11205, Name = "Nur Sari", BirthDate = new DateOnly(1922, 4, 27)},
            new Person(){PersonId = 11898, Name = "Jose Hernandez", BirthDate = new DateOnly(2011, 5, 3)},
            new Person(){PersonId = 12130, Name = "Kenji Sato", BirthDate = new DateOnly(2004, 1, 9)},
}.AsQueryable();
```

and the dialog to this:

```
@implements IDialogContentComponent<FleuntBlazorWebApp.UI.Pages.People.Person>

<FluentDialogBody>
    <FluentTextField @bind-Value="@Content.Name">Name:</FluentTextField>
    <FluentDatePicker @bind-Value="@Content.BirthDate">Age:</FluentDatePicker>
</FluentDialogBody>

@code{
    [Parameter]
    public FleuntBlazorWebApp.UI.Pages.People.Person Content { get; set; } = default!;

    [CascadingParameter]
    public FluentDialog Dialog { get; set; }

    private async Task SaveAsync()
    {
        await Dialog.CloseAsync(Content);
    }

    private async Task CancelAsync()
    {
        await Dialog.CancelAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: now i only have to fix the bind-value of the datepicker